# Tengo problemas con el componente rowsorter, #java

Tags: java, excepciones

tengo un problema con el componente `rowsorter`, explico:

Tengo un módulo con una consulta vía `JcomboBox`, lleno un `JTable` (el `JTable` está dentro de un `JScrollPane`) con esa consulta y tengo un `JtextField` para buscar a la persona en la consulta, en este `JTextField` tengo implementado el rowsorter mediante el evento `keyReleased`, funciona bien, para la primera consulta, pero si cambio la consulta en el `comboBox` y doy en busqueda me regresa esta excepción, ¿qúe podría hacer? alguien que le haya ocurrido esto:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsInserted(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsInserted(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.addRow(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.addRow(Unknown Source)
    at ti.snfco.NominaYCapitalHumano.service.InternalFrameIncapacidad.mostrarDatosEmpleadoIncapacidad(InternalFrameIncapacidad.java:804)
    at ti.snfco.NominaYCapitalHumano.service.InternalFrameIncapacidad$2.actionPerformed(InternalFrameIncapacidad.java:173)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

y el metodo que llena esa tabla:

```
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            datos[0] = resultSet.getString(1);
            datos[1] = resultSet.getString(2);
            datos[2] = resultSet.getString(3);
            datos[3] = resultSet.getString(4);
            datos[4] = resultSet.getString(5);
            datos[5] = resultSet.getString(6);
            datos[6] = resultSet.getString(7);
            datos[7] = resultSet.getString(8);
            datos[8] = resultSet.getString(9);
            datos[9] = resultSet.getString(10);
            modelo.addRow(datos);
        }
        tableIncapacidad.setModel(modelo);

        //aquí lleno el rowsorter del modelo.
        ***rowSorter = new TableRowSorter(modelo);
        tableIncapacidad.setRowSorter(rowSorter);***

    } catch (SQLException el) {
        el.printStackTrace();
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        el.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        LOG.info("Excepcion: " + errors);
    } finally {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ep) {
            ep.printStackTrace();
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            ep.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            LOG.info("Excepcion: " + errors);
        }
    }
```

y desde el `JTextField` hago lo siguiente:

```
textFieldBuscarEmpleado.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

  rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(textFieldBuscarEmpleado.getText().toUpperCase(), IdBusquedaEmple));
}
});
```

tendrán alguna idea de que me falta, gracias a de antemano.